# iOS parse html after server side javascript is run

Tags: html, ios, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a website into an iOS application... Parsing the html tags works fine with hpple, but i want to parse the site after Java scripts and other server side scripts are run... How would I go about doing this?

This is the Java script run on site launch...
I NEED THIS ONE, $('h1').html(sd.number);

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var names = "";
var today = new Date();

$.getJSON('space.json', function(sd) {
$('h1').html(sd.number);
$.each(sd.people, function(key, val) {
var launch = new Date(val.launchdate);
var diff = new Date(today - launch);
var days = Math.floor(diff/1000/60/60/24);
names += ('<a href="' + val.bio + '" target="_blank"><div class="item cf"><div        class="person-name"><h2>' + val.name + '</h2><div class="flag '+ val.country +'"></div><h3>'  + val.title + '</h3></div><div class="person-days"><h4>' + days + '</h4><p>Days in space</p> </div></div></a>');
});
$('#listing').html(names);
});

});
```

Comment: Why can't you just make the request to space.json directly from the app?

Comment: @HugoT how do you do that?

Comment: Make an HTTP Request (Without parsing anything) to the full URL of space.json (add the missing prefix). should end up looking something like `http://www.yourdomain/space.json`. then, just deserialize the JSON Response as usual.

Comment: @AlonAmir thank you sooooooooo much!!! You solved all my problems, your help is greatly appreciated! Would you like to put that in the answer section so I can vote it up and checkmark it?

Comment: @iDevMartin Just did : }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an HTTP Request (Without parsing anything) to the full URL of space.json (add the missing prefix). should end up looking something like http://www.yourdomain/space.json. then, just deserialize the JSON Response as usual.